# sox convert raw audio to wav gives error although all option are defined

Tags: sox

I have some raw audio data I try to convert with sox like this:

```
sox -r 44100 -b 16 -c 1 -L -e signed-integer /infiles/recording.dat /outfiles/recording.wav
```

this gives me the following error:

```
sox FAIL formats: bad input format for file `/infiles/recording.dat': data encoding or sample size was not specified
```

Do you have any idea what I am missing? I just don't get what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 6):

with `-t raw`, it's working:

```
sox -t raw -r 44100 -b 16 -c 1 -L -e signed-integer /infiles/recording.dat /outfiles/recording.wav
```